# Adding WFS layers to leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am able to add a `WMS` layer to a **leaflet** map, but I don't see the possibility of adding `WFS` layers based on leaflet's API documentation.

Are there any workaround for it?

Comment: Check out this post with a similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/how-to-add-geoserver-wfs-to-leaflet-js-application

Comment: Go to http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html and search for WFS there.